# Plotly stack graph array values

Tags: python, statistics, plotly

How to stack values of an entire Y array for an X value?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

forx = [1,2,3,4,5]
fory = [[4,6,8], [2,9], [5], [3,1,5,2], [6,8]]

data = []

for idx, i in enumerate(forx):
          data.append(go.Bar(name=str(i), x=forx, y=fory[idx]))

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

For X-axis value 1 to stack Y-axis array [4,6,8], instead of 0 index from all arrays 4,2,5,3,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can represent your case with a double-entry array:

```
import pandas as pd

forx = [1,2,3,4,5]
fory = [[4,6,8], [2,9], [5], [3,1,5,2], [6,8]]
df= pd.DataFrame(fory, index=forx, dtype=float)
```

the table looks like :

```
     0    1    2    3
1  4.0  6.0  8.0  NaN
2  2.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
3  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  3.0  1.0  5.0  2.0
5  6.0  8.0  NaN  NaN
```

Now plotly.express is very good at reading tables like this

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, mode='stack', labels={'index':'forx', 'value':'fory', 'variable':'series'})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `y` argument in `go.Bar(..., y=y)` receives the y values **over categories**, meaning layer by layer. So, the `data` should get one layer of stacks in each iteration.

You can get what you are looking for by transposing the `fory` values and adding 0s for layers that don't have any values. Or just re-arrange the `fory` by hand to a layer-wise nested list.

This would give you what you want:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

forx = [1,2,3,4,5]
fory = np.array([[4,6,8,0], [2,9,0,0], [5,0,0,0], [3,1,5,2], [6,8,0,0]])
fory_layerwise = fory.T # transposing to a layered format

num_layers = 4

data = []

for layer in range(num_layers):
          data.append(go.Bar(name="layer "+str(layer), x=forx, y=fory_layerwise[layer]))

fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```